# How to solve a rendering exception that happens because of width?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was able to run my code perfectly, but after I added a gesture detector and put a navigtor.pop(), weird exceptions started to face my to-do app.

First here is the code that's causing the problem:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Task extends StatefulWidget {
  static const Routename = '/Task';
  @override
  TaskState createState() => TaskState();
}

class TaskState extends State<Task> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
                child: Column(children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(24)),
            Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/back_arrow_icon.png')),
            Expanded(
                child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: ' Enter your New Task',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.grey),
                  border: InputBorder.none),
            ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ]))));
  }
}
```

I also faced a flutter error which is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3hIp.png)

And a Rendering exception that says:

> The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
> RenderPointerListener object was given an infinite size during layout.

Any suggestions on how to fix my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `GestureDetector` does not have a child, it grows to fit the parent instead.

By default a GestureDetector with an invisible child ignores touches.

Try adding a child to GestureDetector.

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  },
  child: Text('Back'),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you didn't wrapped your GestureDetector around another widget (child) like this:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  },
  child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/back_arrow_icon.png')),
),
```

Comment: but the child is optional property right?

Comment: for some reason it is, but I don't think it can work without a child, because the onTap method gets called when the child is tapped, if there is no child the widget becomes useless

Comment: @Elimantas G cleared. Thank You!